# Black window with "less", "nano", or "screen" - WSL - Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: windows-10, screen, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nano, less

I'm using Windows Subsystem Linux with Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on my laptop (OS: Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC).

It worked flawlessly until a few days ago when I suddenly could not use `less`, `nano`, `screen` etc. anymore. Whenever I use one of these commands, I just see a **blinking dash in the top left corner** but no text is visible:

[image: demonstration of issue]

I can get back to the normal console when pressing the respective keys (e.g. <kbd>q</kbd> for *less*, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> for *screen*), and then I can see the content from the previous command:

[image: recovery demonstration]

So there seems to be something broken, but if possible I would like to not have to uninstall and reinstall all of WSL since I would also lose my conda environments, etc.

WSL System Information:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds a lot like [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7660) with a recent Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC update -- Most likely KB5006368.  Also found in [this Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1684867/1210833) question.

Two possible solutions:

- `export TERM=xterm-color` in your startup (e.g. `~/.bashrc`)
- Uninstall KB5006368

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Adding "export TERM=xterm-color" to my "~/.bashrc" solved the issue!